# In After effects how can I store the start and end point values of a gradient on one layer to generate the opposite values in another layer

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, automation

my composition width is 4480

I have 2 layers with a gradient ramp on each

once I've entered the start and end position of the gradient on the first layer I need to have the opposite equivalent start and end position values of that gradient generated in the second layer's gradient.

So with a comp width of 4480 if gradient 1 start x is 1000 and end x is 1250 then gradient 2 start x should be 3480 and end x is 3230. The Y is going to have a fixed position.
Ideally I'd like to tie in the start x and end x of the first graident to an expression control such as a slider so i can  adjust the position of the points simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to your other question:
[In After Effects how can I generate the value of an opposite x position and then send that value to an effect on another layer?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/33193/in-after-effects-how-can-i-generate-the-value-of-an-opposite-x-position-and-then/33201#33201)

The answer is the same. Use a pick whip to link two controllers together.

Comment: yes i tried the answer on the other question but that seemed to duplicate the output of the first gradient onto the other layer, if i change the start point on  gradient 2 as on the answer on the other question then it shifts the two x's apart so i figured i must be asking the question incorrectly. I'm obviously a bit lost when it comes to pickwhipping two controllers together to get the desired outcome